# Finding and extracting text contained in a list

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

So I have a large data table. One of the columns includes a unique ID, let's call it a fingerprint. In the infinite wisdom of the people who created the table, 1) The fingerprint isn't located anywhere else in the table. 2) The fingerprint was written in manually by people as they added to the table. 3) There's no standard way of writing in the fingerprint. Sometimes it's at the start, the middle, the end, or anywhere inbetween, any length. Sometimes it's squeezed in with text, sometimes it has spaces around it. Fun.

I have a master list of all fingerprints. It's a named range FINGERPRINTS. Hurray! Using

```
 =SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(FINGERPRINT,O2)))
```

, I was able to flag entries that have fingerprints, and those that don't have any. I'm struggling at this point to actually extract the fingerprints out of the text. I have a poor solution including index-match-mid where I manually move the starting point (each fingerprint is 9 digits long), copy-paste when I get a hit, and move on, but I'd like to automate the process.

```
   =INDEX(FINGERPRINT,MATCH(MID(N3797,1,9),FINGERPRINT,0)).
```

Ideally, somehow, I can get the 1 in Mid to return the result the search function is finding - I just can't fathom how to get it to play nicely!

Currently trying :

http://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/excel-search-string-for-a-list-of-words - It's almost perfect. For some reason some of my fingerprints are triggering twice in a search, which is wrong. Further investigation needed.

Edit 3: Almost works perfectly! For some reason, some cells with blahblahblah are triggers a fingerprint, even though none exist. Also, it's triggering different fingerprints for each. Hmm....

Comment: Does the second formula extract the desire value?  If so place it in an unused column, and then place your cursor in the lower right corner.  The cursor should change shape.  Drag downward to the last row, and the formula will be duplicated across all the 1000's of rows automatically.  Have you considered parsing the data so you can convert it into a database?

Comment: The formula extracts the desired value only when the desired value is at the start of the text. So, when the cell is FINGERPRINTblahblahblah. I need it to find BlahlblahFINGERPRINTblahblah as well.

Answer (score 1):

Use your first in your second:

```
=INDEX(FINGERPRINT,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(FINGERPRINT,O2)),0))
```

And enter with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

G1:G4 is a range named `FINGERPRINT`

[image]

Comment: Won't that just give a 1 for the matches, since the ISNUMBER just gives a true/false reading for if there is a position, and not the actual position/location? Also, matching True as a value?

Comment: No the ISNUMBER will return an array to the match of True/False and the Match will find the first in that array that returns True and return the relative position to the INDEX.  make sure you force the Array formula with Ctrl-Shift-Enter.  @Selkie

Comment: @Selkie see edit for proof.